# Termination ends orientation in toroidal transformer

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply

I need to wind a toroidal transformer for a push/pull switch mode power supply (12V DC to 30-0-30 VDC). It would be much better for my pcb layout if primary endings would be at 12 o'clock and secondary at 9 o'clock. Would it cause any problems if wired in that manner?
Also is it important that primary winding would be equally spread acroos the core? And if yes is it better to leave bigger pitch or increase number of turns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the experience I have here at the company I work for and also some studies I did, if you do not distribute the coils evenly throughout the core, there will be magnetic field inside the toroid, that means that the stray field has increased (ie , there will be more dispersed field, greater inductances and inductive couplings).

Transformers are usually made with concentric windings. When this does not happen, the following is observed:

- The transformer ratio can be measured and gives satisfactory results if no load is present in the secondary;
- When a load is applied to the secondary, there will be a lot of stray field and, therefore, a lot of voltage drop.